# print string contain turkey characters in java

Tags: java, string

I am creating a string in my spring controller, it contain turkish characters

String str1 = "iş ortaklığı";

If i try to print it like
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out,true,"UTF-8"));
              System.out.println(s);

**output is** iÅŸ ortaklÄ±ÄŸÄ±

byte[] utf81 = str1.getBytes("UTF-8");
             test3 = new String(utf8);

```
        System.out.println(test3);
```

**output is** iÅŸ ortaklÄ±ÄŸÄ±

byte[] utf8 = str1.getBytes("windows-1254");
             test3 = new String("windows-1254");

**output is** iÃ¾ ortaklÃ½Ã°Ã½

**But All the above code works fine in console program that is main method**
main method prints output like
 iş ortaklığı

Any suggetion must appriciable

Comment: and your question is what, exactly?

Comment: that string is not print in spring controller

Comment: That still isn't a question.

Answer (score 2):

If you replace

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out,true,"UTF-8"));
```

with

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out),true,"UTF-8"));
```

then you'll get a `System.out` that UTF-8 encodes textual content to stdout instead of reencoding over the default encoding.

[Java, default encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128617/java-default-encoding) explains Java's default encoding and how to manipulate that.  If you have control over how your program is run, you might want to force the default encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: still its not working for me in my spring controller output is iÅŸ ortaklÄ±ÄŸÄ±

Comment: @aat, have you looked at that output under hexdump to see if it is properly UTF-8 encoded or whether the reader that you're using is expecting a different encoding?

Comment: thanks for reply actually i am working in windows if i run my project in Linux its working still confusing with windows

Comment: @aat, There is a [Windows version of `hexdump`](http://www.richpasco.org/utilities/hexdump.html).