# java ubuntu support languages

Tags: java, ubuntu, character-encoding

I'm writing a java app that should support multiple languages. The text is already available in different languages. it is unknown in advance.

In case i print it to `System.out` or to a log or to a socket it appears as question mark (?) when running on Ubuntu server.

Running on my local windows machine it works. in both cases i didn't change the file.encoding but using the system defaults (isn't it "UTF-8" for java if its not set?)

I assume its related to encoding but need your help.

Comment: "In case i print it..." - what is "it"? How exactly did you implement the support for multiple languages? Show your code. Right now, your question contains too little information for someone to give you a useful answer. The default character encoding is not always UTF-8, it depends on the system (and on Windows it is most likely not UTF-8).

Comment: on ubuntu the follwoing code: System.out("שלום"); // display as ????

Comment: Do you hold all translations in properties files?

Comment: The default is not UTF-8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006276/what-is-the-default-encoding-of-the-jvm

Comment: i'm getting the String text from socket (read fine). Trying to set the following didn't work:
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding jvm argument: -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" worked