# What is the default charset for base64Decode() function in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to decode a file using base64Decode() function in XPath in WSO2 ESB but I am failling to do that.

What is the default charset for base64Decode()?

Answer (score 0):

The default charset (or encoding) depends on the default [encoding of the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006276/what-is-the-default-encoding-of-the-jvm), which again depends on the OS.

- **Windows** has the default encoding **ANSI (cp1252)**
- **Linux** usually uses **UTF-8**.

So you may set the charset with a [JVM parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding) yourself if you want to be sure.