# Qt Cyrillic symbol in dynamicCall

Tags: c++, qt, character-encoding

I try to call an OLE object with parameters - Russian characters, but as a result I get a bad encoding at the output (the OLE driver logs requests). Supported encoding Windows-1251 and UTF-8, but can't send text correctly. I do this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    QString fileToPrint = (qApp->applicationDirPath()+"/"+"test.txt";

       QFile filePrt(fileToPrint);

          QTextStream inPrt(& filePrt);
          inPrt.setCodec("Windows-1251");

          if(!filePrt.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
          {
              qDebug() << "File failed to open";
              return;
          }

         QStringList toPrint = inPrt.readAll().trimmed().split("\n");

QByteArray strEncSend;

strEncSend+=toPrint [i].replace("\f", "");

object.dynamicCall("FreeTextLine(\""+strEncSend+"\")");
```

but in logs I get:

```
02.11.2021 12:25:17.87|Debug|вызов отработан: FreeTextLine("???°?????µ?»?°?", None) = Success
```

I also tried it through:

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("windows-1251");
                QByteArray strEnc = codec->fromUnicode(toPrint [i].replace("\f", ""));
```

Please help, how to set the encoding correctly? Thanks!

Comment: And that FreeTextLine is some COM object method? What text encoding does it expect? Can you hardcode this object.dynamicCall("FreeTextLine(\"правильный текст\")) and see the expected result?

Comment: yes, FreeTextLine is COM object method. object.dynamicCall("FreeTextLine(\"правильный текст\")) is the same - wrong encoding

Comment: Not really Qt problem? Find out what text encoding works first then? Or what text?

Comment: try  `QTextCodec::codecForName("KOI8-R")`

Comment: QTextCodec::codecForName("KOI8-R")  - the same. I think it's Qt trouble, on Java all is ok

Comment: Then it does seem to be encoding. Try using UTF-8 or what Java returns for Charset.defaultCharset() See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006276/what-is-the-default-encoding-of-the-jvm