# Problem with RequestParam string encoding

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem with encoding request param in Spring. I have a GetMapping:

```
public DTO getAll(@RequestParam final Long pageSize,
                  @RequestParam(required = false) final String searchString,
                  @RequestParam final Long pageNumber) {
    log.debug("Search text is: {}", searchString);
}
```

When I write numbers or english symbols in searchString, it works correct, but when I write, for example, russian words, i get this

> Search text is: ÐºÐ°Ð·Ð°Ð½Ñ�ÐºÐ¹

Can anybody help?

Comment: Who is sending that request? Because it sounds like an encoding problem. Either your server  or the caller is not running on the correct encoding (probably just UTF-8).

Comment: Oh, i forgot. In IntellijIdea all works perfect. But when i build application in war and deploy on server, I see this problem

Comment: @Lino i send requests in Postman

Comment: @SeventhDonkey encode above russian words in hexadecimal format and then send in searchString, you will get correct output

Comment: What is the default encoding your environment? If it is not UTF-8 then you need to set it to UTF-8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006276/what-is-the-default-encoding-of-the-jvm